# How to open a form twice with same object values?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm dealing with an C# windows form application.

I need to be able to open a form twice.

My program includes a basic form. This form contains several panels. A form is displayed in each panel. There is a button under each panel. I need that when each button is pressed, the form associated with it will be displayed larger. < Maximized >

On the other hand, I want the values shown in the panel to correspond with the values shown in the enlarged form. It means that if I click on the < bigger button > and the same form is displayed in a bigger size. If I make a change in it, those changes will be applied in the form in the panel and vice versa.

I cannot create two different objects from the same form. Because these two objects are completely independent from each other and changes in one do not affect the other.

What should I do to implement this interface?

Comment: Don't create "new" every time.

Comment: Are you telling me that I can write _Formobject.show() twice in my application .

Comment: See my code here.  You have to capture the form close event and stop it from closing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: You can bind the `Size` or `ClientSize` properties to ApplicationSettings (if you're targeting .NET 6+, you have to do it *manually*, there's no designer support for it, yet)

Comment: You can definitely show the same form twice.  You might want to narrow the scope of this question, right now you're asking several things (open two forms, update automatically, maximize from panel).